# SQL syntax error while getting the last records of the each user from the multiple tables, Also not getting the output

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables `tbl_lead, tbl_documentsPickup` and `tbl_bankdata`. In the `tbl_lead` table, I am inserting personal information. In the `tbl_documentsPickup`, I am inserting the document information which is more than one record for each user and In `tbl_bankdata`, Inserting the bank data which is more than one record for each user.

Now what I am doing is, I have to display the last record of each user from `tbl_documentsPickup` and `tbl_bankdata`. Also, there is a possibility that `tbl_documentsPickup` and `tbl_bankdata` can be empty for users.

**tbl_lead**

```
 lead_id | name | email       | mobile     | 
    1    | qwsd |cm@gmail.com | 1111111111 |
    2    | mjhd |qs@gmail.com | 2222222222 |
    3    | oiuy |gh@gmail.com | 3333333333 | 
    4    | qswe |4e@gmail.com | 4444444444 |
```

**tbl_documentsPickup**

```
  doc_id | lead_id| d_pickupStatus| d_date_of_created   
    1    | 1      | 1             | 2019-08-29 00:53:33
    2    | 2      | 1             | 2019-08-29 12:40:14
    3    | 1      | 2             | 2019-08-29 14:14:54
    4    | 3      | 1             | 2019-08-29 14:26:22
    5    | 3      | 3             | 2019-08-29 15:35:03
```

**tbl_bankdata**

```
 bank_id |p_id| lead_id| d_fileStatus  | date_of_added 
    1    | 1  |   1    | 1             | 2019-08-30 00:53:33
    2    | 2  |   2    | 3             | 2019-08-30 12:40:14
    3    | 3  |   1    | 4             | 2019-08-30 11:14:54
    4    | 4  |   3    | 1             | 2019-08-30 12:26:22
    5    | 5  |   3    | 2             | 2019-08-30 12:26:22
```

I am using below query but I am getting the error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

```
$query="
SELECT * FROM tbl_lead 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT d.* FROM tbl_documentsPickup d 
    INNER JOIN (
         SELECT lead_id, d_pickupStatus,  MAX(d_date_of_created) AS maxdt_doc
         FROM tbl_documentsPickup GROUP BY lead_id
    ) e ON d.`lead_id`=e.`lead_id` AND d.`d_date_of_created`=e.`maxdt_doc`
) as tbl_document 
LEFT JOIN (
    select lead_id, b_bankDoneStatus, max(date_of_added) as latest 
    from tbl_bankdata group by lead_id HAVING max(`date_of_added`) = latest 
 ) r on tbl_lead.lead_id=r.lead_id";
 $getQuery= $this->db->query($query);
 return $getQuery->result();
```

Comment: Why do you tag MySQL, when you are actually using MariaDB? And which version are you using?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I am using PHP and PHPMyAdmin for the database.  I run the query and I found this error. Version information: 4.8.3 I am using

Comment: Your first `LEFT JOIN` is missing an `ON` clause.

Comment: `PHPMyAdmin` is not a database it is a UI usually to work with a mysql db. Maria and mysql are similiar, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120178/whats-the-difference-between-mariadb-and-mysql, but from your error message you are using maria.

Comment: 4.8.3 is your PhpMyAdmin version. This is just an app to work with a DBMS. Your DBMS is MariaDB, as can be seen from the error message. Its version is shown in PhpMyAdmin on the right (Database Server | Server Version). You should also be able to see it with `select @@version;` or `select version();`

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, Thanks for the information. Apologies for my bad.

Comment: So, which is your MariaDB version? Tell us.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, it's 10.1.36-MariaDB

Comment: Then Windows functions like `ROW_NUMBER` are not available. But GMB's first query and mine should both work for you.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, Yes GMB, and your query both are working. I am trying to implement it with my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this with correlated subqueries in the `on` clause of the `left join`s, as follows:

```
select l.*, d.*, b.*
from 
    tbl_lead l
    left join tbl_documentsPickup d 
        on  d.lead_id = l.lead_id
        and d.d_date_of_created  = (
            select max(d_date_of_created) 
            from tbl_documentsPickup d1 
            where d1.lead_id = d.lead_id
        )
    left join tbl_bankdata b 
        on  b.lead_id = l.lead_id
        and d.date_of_added = (
            select max(date_of_added) 
            from tbl_bankdata b1 
            where b1.lead_id = b.lead_id
        )
```

For performance, you want indexes on:

```
tbl_documentsPickup(lead_id, d_date_of_created)
tbl_bankdata(lead_id, date_of_added)
```

In MariaDB 10.2 or higher, another option is to use window functions:

```
select l.*, d.*, b.*
from 
    tbl_lead l
    left join 
        ( 
            select 
                d.*, 
                row_number() over(partition by lead_id order by d_date_of_created desc) rn 
            from tbl_documentsPickup d
        ) d on d.lead_id = l.lead_id and d.rn = 1
    left join 
        (
            select 
                b.*, 
                row_number() over(partition by lead_id order by date_of_added desc) rn 
            from tbl_bankdata b
        ) b on b.lead_id = l.lead_id and b.rn = 1
```

Comment: Give me some time to check your answer.

Comment: I am getting on error  #1054 - Unknown column 'b.lead_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: @NarendraVerma: I just edited my answer, please try the new query... Thanks!

Comment: let me check again.

Comment: I am getting the error.
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by lead_id order by d_date_of_created desc) rn
            from tbl' at line 8

Comment: I tried your first query I change the table name in left join select l.*, d.*, b.*
from 
    tbl_lead l
    left join tbl_documentsPickup d 
        on  l.lead_id = d.lead_id
        and d.d_date_of_created  = (
            select max(d_date_of_created) from tbl_documentsPickup d1 where d1.lead_id = d.lead_id
        )
    left join tbl_bankdata b 
        on  l.lead_id = b.lead_id
        and b.date_of_added   = (
            select max(date_of_added) from tbl_bankdata b1 where b1.lead_id = b.lead_id
        )

Comment: The first query looks fine to me. The second is lacking table aliases in the subqueries (e.g. you are selecting `d.*`, but the table isn't aliased `d`). Apart from this, it looks fine, too. `ROW_NUMBER` is available as of MariaDB 10.2.

Comment: @GMB, Thanks for the help, I used the first query and it's working perfectly.

Comment: @GMB, Sorry to disturb you again. I am getting one issue in the first query. I mean in the second left join I have more one records of each user but I am getting all the records from the tbl_bankdata. it should display the last record from tbl_bankdata.  Can you help me out?

Comment: why I am getting the more than one because in the tbl_bankdata date_of_added can be same date and time. I mean I am submitting multiple records at the same time. You can check the in the tbl_bankdata table of lead id 3

Answer (score 1):

This is your query. (I've removed the superfluous backticks.)

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_lead 
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT d.* 
  FROM tbl_documentsPickup d 
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT lead_id, d_pickupStatus, MAX(d_date_of_created) AS maxdt_doc 
    FROM tbl_documentsPickup
    GROUP BY lead_id
  ) e ON d.lead_id = e.lead_id AND d.d_date_of_created = e.maxdt_doc
) as tbl_document 
LEFT JOIN 
(
  select lead_id, b_bankDoneStatus, max(date_of_added) as latest 
  from tbl_bankdata 
  group by lead_id 
  HAVING max(date_of_added) = latest 
) r on tbl_lead.lead_id = r.lead_id;
```

Here are the things you are doing wrong:

1. You are selecting `d_pickupStatus` in your `e` subquery. But as you are grouping by `lead_id` only, you get one `d_pickupStatus` per `lead_id` arbitrarily picked. That doesn't seem to make much sense.
2. You left outer join `tbl_document`, but there is no join condition. You are missing the `ON` clause. That should be the syntax error you are seeing, I guess.
3. Your `r` subquery makes no sense at all to me. First you are selecting an arbitrarily picked value again (`b_bankDoneStatus`). And then you use a `HAVING` clause where you say that a value shall match itself. (`latest` is your alias name for `max(date_of_added)`, so `max(date_of_added) = latest` is always true.)

Here is one way to get the last entries per `lead_id` from `tbl_documentspickup` and `tbl_bankdata`.

```
select * 
from tbl_lead 
left join 
(
  select *
  from tbl_documentspickup
  where (lead_id, d_date_of_created) in
  (
    select lead_id, max(d_date_of_created)
    from tbl_documentspickup
    group by lead_id
  )
) latest_documentspickup using (lead_id)
left join 
(
  select *
  from tbl_bankdata 
  where (lead_id, date_of_added) in
  (
    select lead_id, max(date_of_added)
    from tbl_bankdata
    group by lead_id
  )
) latest_bankdata using (lead_id)
order by lead_id;
```

Comment: Give me some time to understand your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information. Upvote from my side.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you. I have one doubt in your query, I need to know from first table tbl_lead and primary id is lead_id. so my doubt is where did you add that primary id in your query?

Comment: I don't understand your question. `tbl_lead` has a unique column `lead_id`. The same is true for the two subqueries (provided that lead_id + datetime are unique in the tables). I'm joining the two subqueires to the `tbl_lead` with `using (lead_id)`. So, what is you think is missing?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, There was some internet issue. My doubt is if I change from lead_id to id of the table tbl_lead then in the query should I need to update id?

Comment: Can you help me in this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699077/how-to-get-the-latest-records-of-the-each-user