# How to get the latest records of the each user?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, one is the login and the second is the details of the company.
The below are the structure of the table. (I was trying online to add the SQL query and table but I am getting the error `Help: near "ENGINE": syntax error`. So I added it below)

**login**

```
login_id | username | password 
1        | abc      | ****     
2        | xyz      | ****     
3        | oiu      | ****
```

**company**

```
company_id | company_name | content      | size | date_of_added | login_id
1          | oiuyt        | some content | 12   | 2021-05-05    | 1
2          | lddjl        | some content | 13   | 2021-05-05    | 2
3          | kjhgf        | some content | 15   | 2021-05-05    | 1
4          | qwedrr       | some content | 16   | 2021-05-05    | 1
5          | qwesd        | some content | 20   | 2021-05-05    | 3
6          | uwewe        | some content | 09   | 2021-05-05    | 2
```

My issue is, I have to show the latest records of each login user.
My expected output is,

```
company_id | company_name | content      | size | date_of_added | login_id | username
  4        | qwedrr       | some content | 16   | 2021-05-05    | 1        | abc
  6        | uwewe        | some content | 09   | 2021-05-05    | 2        | xyz
  5        | qwesd        | some content | 20   | 2021-05-05    | 3        | oiu

  and so on
```

I tried the below query but I am getting all the records

```
select l.*, c.*
from 
    login l
     left join company c 
        on  l.login_id = c.login_id
        and c.date_of_created  = (
            select max(date_of_created) 
            from company c1 
            where c1.company_id = c.company_id
        )
```

Comment: *I have to show the last records of each login user.* What is "last"? What ordering provides this?

Comment: @Akina, typo mistake,  I mean I have a total of 6 records in the company table and using login id I have to display the latest records. Please check my expected output

Comment: And again - what is "latest"? specify ORDER BY expression which allows to distinguish this. The most common criteria is date, but all `date_of_added` values are equal whereas the expression must provide uniqueness for "latest" term to make sense.

Comment: @Akina, I have a time along with the date.

Comment: Yes. So the ordering by it does not provide rows uniqueness, so the term 'latest' is ambiguous.

Comment: @Akina, Please suggest to me how can I solve this issue?

Comment: I don't know - you're the only man who can define this. Maybe, greater `company.company_id` matches more recent creation datetime and may be used for ordering and defining what row is the most last?

Comment: @Akina I am adding multiple records to the company table with the login id and I have to get the records of the latest row. for example.. login id 1 has three rows and I have to show company id 4 rows

Comment: *login id 1 has three rows and I have to show company id 4 rows* Why 4 and not some other? what definite value causes this? maybe this is because the value 4 is maximal one from all existing (1,3 and 4) for this login?

Comment: Can you maybe add an auto increment column that could be used to id rows and provide an order? Or maybe add a time component to the date_of_added field (something like yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss for example). Otherwise like @Akina said, it's impossible to know what "latest" entry is.

Comment: I have a time in the date I haven't added in the question because all are the same..I have important the excel sheet. so I am getting date and time same.. and about increment i have login_id and company id is the auto increment

Comment: Again: If the date/time is the same for all rows, how could you possibly know which is first and which is last? Please tell us how you realized that it's company_id 4 for login_id 1 and not, say, company_id 3?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "latest" is "with maximal `id`":

```sql
SELECT c1.*, login.username 
FROM company c1
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(c2.company_id) company_id, c2.login_id
       FROM company c2
       GROUP BY c2.login_id ) c3 USING (company_id, login_id)
JOIN login USING (login_id)
```

Comment: Getting error  #1052 - Column 'login_id' in from clause is ambiguous

Comment: @NarenVerma Sorry. Edited.